# Laravel - Validation with custom column name

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

this is inside  the database: 
[image]

.

and the html form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="fc_fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
    <input type="email" name="fc_email_addr" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="password" name="fc_pwd" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="fc_pwd_confirmation" placeholder="Repeat Password" />
</form>
```

.

and the validation code is:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'fc_fullname' => 'required|string|max:255|exists:admins,name',
        'fc_email_addr' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:admins,email',
        'fc_pwd' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed|exists:admins,password',
])->validate();
```

.

.

So, currently, I am able to use `custom column name` by using `exists` and `unique` Validation rules.

But I don't want to use the `exists` rule. I just want to specify custom column name ONLY.

Is there any other rules or trick to specify the column name in database table?

Comment: Hello, what are you trying to achieve here? If you use exists, it will check if the inserted value already exists in the column. For example, if you check it for password, the inserted password will check if it is already available in the password column of admins table. But the password should be encrypted. So what are you looking for actually?

Comment: yes i know...

`exists` will check if the value exist in the table. If value already exist, the value is VALID.
And for `unique`, it also will check if the value exist in the table. But for this rule, if value already exist, the value is INVALID.

I already state 'What I want try to achieve' in the question. Stackoverflow is for all people around the world, so you should be ready to understand english in different slang or different accent.

By the way, answer from @GAURAV VAGHELA is what I am looking for. I already mark his answer as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You can try this.

```
$attribute = array(
   'fc_fullname' => 'name',
   'fc_email_addr' => 'email',  
   'fc_pwd' => 'password',
);

$validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );
$validator->setAttributeNames($attribute);
```

Comment: this is what I want. Thank you. I just tried it and it's working.